# How to draw axis lines(x, y,z) in android with or without openGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to show axis(x, y and Z) line in my android application.
These will be axis lines. for example: x axis will be from -50 to +50. for drawing x axis I need not to give any y or z value.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw lines in general, or is there something specific about axis lines that you need help with? Are you expecting the camera to move; if so, how?

Comment: I am using openGl and android and my 3D object is rotating. So my axis will also rotate along with object.